# Using different versions of the same JAR at runtime

Tags: java, jar

I have a requirement where I need to refer to two different versions of the same JAR in my application at runtime: `fop.jar` (v1.0) in certain cases and `fop 1.1.jar` in certain other cases.

How can I achieve this?

I cannot load it dynamically as my EAR will not be compiled without this.

Comment: The key thing is: that definitely requires you to use Custom class loaders; so that one part of your application runs with class X v1.0; and another one uses class X v1.1. That is possible to do, but requires *careful* designing. I would rather spent brain power on figuring ways to **not** have the requirement to use two different version of the same JAR.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This is what we are trying to do but the old code base has lot of incompatible xsl which is hard to correct in a short span of time. I am looking at a tactical solution to acheive without making changes to the old xsl.

Comment: And you think that **enabling** your old code base to use different class loaders will be a less risky/time consuming idea? My gut feeling is: that could be even harder.

Comment: Yes..Thought so...

Comment: Then I suggest that you do some research on how to do that (you should find plenty of information here and other sites) ... and go try it. You see, this is quite a lot of work, which heavily depends on your current solution. That is nothing that we can reasonable help with. If at all, you should put up a **very specific** code example to illustrate one of the APIs that need different versions.

Comment: Just an idea: what about creating small independent services that handle the different versions and expose a webservice interface? You should then be able to decide which of the different webservices to call (it still depends on your architecture, environment, requirements etc.)

Comment: @GaneshHegde Welcome to StackOverflow! I've suggested some changes to the question and title based on what's been discussed in the comments, hopefully that will make easier to understand what are you trying to achieve. My edit is in the review queue now waiting for approval. Please have a look and check if what I've changed makes sense and describes what you are actually trying to achieve accurately: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14057990

Comment: Thanks Jose for your edits and I am trying to implement Thomas's idea.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this problem in a very hackish way. I needed version 1.5 and 2 of pdfbox for some reason. So I extracted all contents of the .jar file into a temp directory, then using Notepad++ search and replace in files I replaced org.apache with urg.apache and org/apache with urg/apache (messed up org.apache.commons which I fixed afterwards) then zipped the replaced files to a new .jar. 
Installed it to maven with 
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=pdfbux-1.5.0.jar -DgroupId=urg.apache.pdfbox -DartifactId=pdfbox -Dversion=1.5.0 -Dpackaging=jar

In my pom.xml I have 2 dependencies. version 1.5 using urg.apache
In the code using 1.5 I used import urg.apache...

I know this is a **crazy hack** but it saved me a lot of time